# Cross domain tracking works separately in each domain(not linked)

Tags: google-analytics

Using Google Analytics,
I am trying to track initiated from external site(siteA.com).
At siteA.com, open new window to go main site(siteB.com).

So I put setDomainName("none"), trackPageview, and getLinkerUrl(URL_TO_SiteB) on siteA.com. 
And open URL returned from getLinkerUrl, open new window to go siteB.com
And also put setDomainName("none"), setAllowLinker(true), trackPageview on siteB.com.

But, I think something wrong with this configuration.

At navigation summary, there is no previous page or next page at page tracked from siteA.com.
And strange page(another page of siteB.com) is recorded as previous page of siteB.com.

Is there any missing part of configuration?

In short,
site A > site B linking is not working(there is no page having site A as previous page and there are strange pages used as previous page of site B).

I am struggling with this issue about a month.
I eagerly waiting for your help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using is for tracking iframes.

To setup cross domain tracking in the `<a>` of link to siteB add

`onclick="_gaq.push(['_link', this.href]); return false;"`

Complete details here
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#multipleDomains